# How to change the colors of a barplot in ggplot keeping legend variables same?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I would like to have a colorblind friendly paletter for a barplot in ggplot.
I plot the barplot through this code

```
library(tidyverse)
my_se <- df %>%
  group_by(groups) %>%
  summarise(n=n(),
            sd=sd(mean),
            se=sd/sqrt(n))


    # Standard error
    df %>% 
      left_join(my_se) %>% 
      mutate(zone = factor(zone,labels = c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5","x6","x7","x8","x9","x10","x11"))) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x=zone, y=mean, fill = groups)) + 
      geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
      geom_errorbar(aes(x=zone, ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se), width=0.4, position = position_dodge(.9)) +
      ggtitle("using standard error")+scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("GC", "IP", "MR","CS"))+
      labs(y= an, x = "Land Cover")+theme_bw()+theme(legend.title =element_blank())+
      theme(legend.text=element_text(size=11),axis.text.y=element_text(size=11.5),
            axis.text.x=element_text(size=11.5),axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12))
```

I have made a custom color palette

```
cbPalette <- c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73")
```

But when I add this snippet code:

```
scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette)
```

to my ggplot code it gives me this message

```
Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill', which
will replace the existing scale.
```

Although the colors are changed but my whole legend labels get changed with it. I want to keep my legend variables as "GC", "IP", "MR","CS".

How can I change the colors of the bars with not effecting the legend labels of variables?

Comment: look into the `viridis` and `viridisLite` packages for pre-made colorblind palettes.  These also should print fine in gray-scale I believe.  Easily incorporated into ggplots as `scale_fill_viridis()`  (one example).

Answer (score 2):

Pointing out to great suggestion from @Dave2e you can try this (Data used from similar questions you posted):

```
df %>% 
  left_join(my_se) %>% 
  mutate(zone = factor(zone,labels = c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5","x6","x7","x8","x9","x10","x11"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=zone, y=meangpp, fill = groups)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=zone, ymin=meangpp-se, ymax=meangpp+se), width=0.4, position = position_dodge(.9)) +
  ggtitle("using standard error")+
  scale_fill_manual(labels = c("GC", "IP", "MR","CS"),values=cbPalette)+
  labs(y= 'an', x = "Land Cover")+theme_bw()+theme(legend.title =element_blank())+
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=11),axis.text.y=element_text(size=11.5),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=11.5),axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12))
```

[image]